# Select all the HTML page except the current element

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply a modification on a web page, except on a particular image. To do this, I use this selector : $("*:not(elem)");

When I log the result on the console, the element I don't want to be changed is too selected. But it shouldn't...

```
$('img').on("click", function() {
    darkenBody(this);
    focusElement(this);
});


function darkenBody(elem)
{
    console.log($("*:not(elem)"));
}
```

So I'm searching for a solution to select all my page without selecting the element I'm clicking on...

Comment: Can you please share the html structure? because it really does matter. when selecting and excluding

Comment: You've passed "elem" as a *string literal*.  Try: `$("*"):not(elem)`

Comment: Thank you sir, the problem was the string literal.I used $("*").not(elem) and it now works!